# If $\sim{p}$ then $\left ( p\vee{q} \right )$

Tags: logic

If $p=1$, then what would be the output of this$:\quad\sim{p}\rightarrow{p\vee{q}}$ ? More importantly, what is the intuition behind this ? I'm new to logic, and would appreciate any explanations !

Comment: What do you mean by $(\sim p)\implies (p\text{ or }q)$ ? What are $p$, $q$ ?

Comment: Try with a truth table.... If $p=1$ then $\lnot p=0$.

Comment: Thus $((\lnot p) \to (p \lor q))=1$.

Comment: Because $(0 \to X)=1$ for $X$ whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If $p=1$ means $p$ is true, then $\operatorname {if }\sim p \operatorname { then } (p \operatorname { or } q)$ is true.  An implication is true any time the antecedent, here $\sim p$, is false.  The sentence will also be true any time $q$ is true, because that makes the consequent true.  Your sentence is equivalent to $(p \operatorname { or } q)$